# How to add class to each line in linechart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart

i have draw a line chart i want to give each line a dynamic class.

```
 nv.addGraph(function() {
        height = 450;
        width = $(div).width() - 50;
        chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
            .width(width)
            .height(height);
        var svg = d3.select(div).append("svg")
            .datum(chartsData)
            .call(chart)
            .style({
                'width': width,
                'height': height
            })
```

Data:

```
 data: {
            values: formatedData,
            key: key,
            color: color,
            class: '_class'
        }
```

i have passed the class in the data but it doesn't pick this.. .
i want a class for each line

**EDITED:** 
this is how i add the class in the line.
in the nv.d3.js i have update this function to :

```
  // Update Main (Focus)
                var focusLinesWrap = g.select('.nv-focus .nv-linesWrap')
                    .datum(
                        data
                        .filter(function(d) {
                            return !d.disabled
                        })
                        .map(function(d, i) {
                            return {
                                key: d.key,
                                class: d.class,
                                circleClass: d.circleClass,
                                values: d.values.filter(function(d, i) {
                                    return lines.x()(d, i) >= extent[0] && lines.x()(d, i) <= extent[1];
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    );
```

and process it here :

```
var groups = wrap.select('.nv-groups').selectAll('.nv-group')
groups
    .attr('class', function(d, i) {
                        return d.class + ' nv-group nv-series-' + i
                    })
```

Comment: I can't see any attempt to set the class attribute in your code... what did you try?

Comment: now i have update the nv.d3.js and add class to the line.

Comment: really? where? And `chartsData` is an array of objects with the form `data` right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could not add specific attribute to group of data like this :

```
var groups = wrap.select('.nv-groups').selectAll('.nv-group');
groups.attr('class', function(d, i) {
    return d.class + ' nv-group nv-series-' + i
});
```

Change your code like this and it will work correctly:

```
var groups = wrap.select('.nv-groups').selectAll('.nv-group');
groups.each( function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).attr('class', d.class + ' nv-group nv-series-' + i);
});
```

Other type of code is:

```
var groups = wrap.select('.nv-groups').selectAll('.nv-group');
groups.each( function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this).attr('class',function(){ 
        return  d.class + ' nv-group nv-series-' + i;
    });
});
```

Comment: I think, there are some errors in this anser: 1) Your first sentence is not correct. Why shouldn't it be possible to use the code from the first snippet? This is D3's standard way of setting attribute values on a selection, and, in fact, it should be the way to go to solve OP's problem. 2) Your second snippet contains a very bad error on line 3 when trying to directly assign the string to the selection. 3) This is not really an error, but the third snippet is just a cumbersome way of doing functionally the same as in the first snippet.

Comment: @altocumulus it was just a syntax error, It's not a huge mistake just change 'calss' to 'class'.

Comment: No, the way second snippet is **now** it doesn't make any sense. To set the attribute's value you need to pass a second argument to `.attr()` which will then end up being identical to snippet 3.

Comment: @altocumulus yes I got it, it was a simple way that fixed in new version of d3, now it work correctly.